# Higgs boson propagator and current terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, higgs

[image]

I have been trying to get the scattering amplitude for $u+u \rightarrow u+u$ where $u$ are a specific type of lepton.

From the following diagrams, I can write the Feynman amplitudes as

$$\mathcal{M_1} = -\frac{y_u^2}{2}[\bar{u}(p_3)u(p_1)][\bar{u}(p_4)u(p_2)]\frac{i}{t^2-m_h^2}$$

$$\mathcal{M_2} = -\frac{y_u^2}{2}[\bar{u}(p_4)u(p_1)][\bar{u}(p_3)u(p_2)]\frac{i}{u^2-m_h^2}$$

respectively where $k\equiv t$.

What worries me is that the current terms are absent of gamma matrices (as it should I guess since the Higgs propagator does not contain a metric because it's a scalar boson hence the amplitude this way is a scalar).

First, I need a confirmation if these two amplitudes are correct and if yes I need an explanation why the current terms are absent of gamma matrices.

Comment: Have you ever looked at the Yukawa interaction terms? Where are the gammas, any gammas?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately your reasoning occurred to me after I posted this question.